# How make OncePerRequestFilter called when management.port is different from server port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters, spring-boot-actuator

I have a filter that extends `OncePerRequestFilter`. When I the `management.port=8081` and the `server.port=8080` (or any differing ports), my filter is not called on any 8081 Urls.

The filter is *only* called on 8080 Urls.

How do I make it called on all Urls, including those on 8081?

Filter:

```
@Order( Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE )
public class TestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    public TestFilter()
    {
        System.out.println( "Started" );
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException
    {
        System.out.println( "Checked should not filter" );
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "Filtering" );

        // continue the processing
        filterChain.doFilter( request, response );
    }
}
```

I add it by:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig
{
    @Bean
    public TestFilter testFilter()
    {
        return new TestFilter()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I tried adding `@ManagementContextConfiguration` to my config class, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I was unable to find documentation, it appears the answer is to do **all** of the following:

1. Add a class that's annotated with `@ManagementContextConfiguration`
2. Put that configuration file *outside* the component scan (so spring boot's normal auto-config won't find it)
3. Declare it in META-INF/spring.factories:

META-INF/spring.factories:

before spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE:
`org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementContextConfiguration=com.packageoutsidescan.MyManagementFilterConfigurationClass`

after spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE (`web` subpackage):

`org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=com.packageoutsidescan.MyManagementFilterConfigurationClass`

Comment: For spring-boot-3 you'll have to add a file with name `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration.imports` in `MEAT-INF/spring` folder that will contain the list of files to import (one per line):
```
com.packageoutsidescan.MyManagementFilterConfigurationClass
```