# Apply OncePerRequestFilter to Spring Boot Actuators

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a defined a OncePerRequestFilter. E.g.

```
@Component
public class SomeRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
      final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    //do stuff...
  }
}
```

This is working fine for all requests except the Spring Boot Actuators. These are running one a different port

```
management.server.port=9999
```

For all requests on that port. E.g. `GET http://myapp:9999/health` the filter will not be called.

Is there a way to apply the filters to Actuators as well without involving Spring Security?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691407/12199915

Comment: Okay - that was it. Apparently I need to improve my search skills. If you turn this into an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: once you accept it and dole out the bounty to @alex, I will flag it as a duplicate to keep the platform clean